# modificar campo pantalla usando super

Tags: poo, sap, abap

estoy empezando con las clases y objetos y tengo un problema para entender el uso de la clase 'super'.
Digamos que tengo un campo en pantalla que dependiendo de unas condiciones quiero que no se pueda ingresar datos.
El campo es 'campo' y l método que estoy definiendo sería así:

```
method modificar_pantalla.
   super->modificar_pantalla( if_dynnr = if_dynnr ).
```

Qué tendría que agregar para que el campo no sea editable?

Comment: Hola de nuevo. Parece que está llamando al método modificar_pantalla, definido en la clase base. Comprueba que hace ese método, y si necesitas ampliarlo en la clase derivada. Es algo parecido a hacer un "copy-paste" de código. La funcionalidad del método de la clase base la trasladas a la clase base. Un saludo

Comment: Hola @JakintsuIheslari,
Es un ejercicio que he encontrado. no hay definición de la clase base. El código del método podria ser algo así? (lo pego tal cual porque no se como poner en formato código en un comentario al igual que hacer una pregunta)

LOOP AT SCREEN INTO ls_screen_element.
  IF ls_screen_element-name = 'YOURFIELDNAME'.
    ls_screen_element-INPUT = '0'.
    MODIFY screen FROM ls_screen_element.
  ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.

Answer (score 0):

super invoca al constructor de la clase base (o padre). También sirve para invocar a métodos de la clase base. Se usa para evitar duplicidades, hacer el código más limpio....
Un saludo y bienvenido

Comment: Hola @jakintsu, gracias por tu respuesta. Eso lo entiendo, pero no se qué tendría que poner el método para conseguir la ocultación del campo.